# Keeping forensic cops out

Tags: security

I was just arrested and bonded out immediately. my phone was confiscated.  It was an Android and is there anything I can do to keep them from accessing the contents of my phone? Would deleting my Google account keep them from changing my password? Google will give them their own personal passcode to get into my locked screen and change pin lock.I'm not sure what question to ask,any help would be highly appreciated by me and my family

Comment: I'm not sure if questions like this are allowed, but you could use Android Device Manager to wipe the device. TBH though, if this is seriously going to true forensic analysis by trained LE technicians, it will barely slow them down a few extra hours. If your device wasn't lollipop or Marshmallow with device level encryption, prepare for the fallout of whatever you had in there because they will find it. Although keep in mind that law enforcement will not disclose any information that's in your phone accept what's related to this case

Comment: Thank you for your response I've already used Android device manager and requested to wipe the device but its not locating the device right now because either the phone is dead and also my phone service has been cancelled for that song I'm not sure if the the white free quest will still happen as soon as they try to turn it on I assume that that can only happen whenever the phone is connected to Wi-Fi but they probably know not to do could you tell me a little bit more about how the Android device manager wipe out request work

Comment: Oh, and since it's already been siezed, it is evidence... So if you try to this and they find out (which is quite easy for a trained technician), you will get an added charge of tampering with evidence.

Comment: Yeah,  the wipe request will happen if it can contact Google servers, and you will be charged with tampering with evidence.

Comment: I took that into account before I did it and I weighed the pros and cons and I'll take that case over the ones I could be facing if content s are seen do you think in the process of them hacking into my phone would require them to become to put my phone online because soon as it's online it automatically find Google servers correct??

Comment: By the way, if this a serious charge, anything except device level encryption won't help you... They can JTAG image the chip and view all the data directly. Only Lollipop and Marshmallow device level encryption before it's seized would help. Even if it's wiped, the data is recoverable by trained technicians.

Comment: Ok thank you for your time this news is not very surprising I knew I  had little or no chance to stop this but thank you anyways if you have any other information I might be able to use pkease  send ty for your time

Comment: Sorry...  But unless you had it's encrypted prior to seizure, anything else will just be a short bump in the road for them. They will get any and all information off of your phone,  will just take a few extra hours or days. Expect the worst.

Comment: One last thing do you happen to know the backlog on these types of things how long it takes for devices to actually reach the point of the forensics team cuz I've heard of people waiting in jail for years  before evidence was brought up

Comment: I'm aware that apps like kik and others automatically download the your messages to the phone and some don't the one I'm worried about is Instagram does Instagram download all contents to your phone

Comment: all depends on the state or federal agencies involved and their workload, and the seriousness or urgency of the crime your charged with. It could literally be hours or months.

Comment: We are getting beyond the scope of your question... I would prefer not to continue answering these questions. If the information is there or pending they will get it. If they discover you have Instagram and think it's relevant, they will court order your information from them. If it happens online, expect it to be discovered, because almost nothing unencrypted is private.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there anything I can do to keep them from accessing the contents of
>   my phone?

If they have physical access over phone, then the answers is **no**. If the information was encrypted, then you would stand a chance. However, if that is not the case, then in no time they will have access to your phone and the data it keeps within.

> Would deleting my Google account keep them from changing my password?

No. The data is already written on the storage of your phone. One thing you would do would be wiping your phone using Android Device Manager. However, it won't actually wipe the data really. It'll just make it *overwritable* for other datas to take its place, which will be ineffective anyway. But that for sure will make people realize you got something to hide and might even be considered as tampering the evidence as acejavelin said.

> I'm not sure what question to ask

I think the question you want to ask is *Are they going to certainly learn whatever is on the phone and is there a way to stop them at this point?*

The answers are **yes** and **no** respectively.